# How can I run Linux in 256 color

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, color-management

I want to run a Linux distribution in 256 color.

Doesn't matter which distribution can do it.

I tested Ubuntu 14.04, but it can't run lower than 16 bit. (using /etc/X11/xorg.conf)

Which distribution is better for me, and how can I configure that?

Comment: It would be useful to know why you need only 256 colors. A bit more context may help you get better answers.

Comment: i want to run old program over ssh (X forwarding), it just run on pseudocolor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you want pseudocolor, which isn't well supported anymore. A thread on Xorg a few years ago pointed out a problem with the feature, but concluded by [suggesting that it could work](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2011-September/053334.html) with a vesa driver.  Alternatively, a discussion on a Raspberry Pi forum suggested using `Xephyr` (a nested X server) in which one could run a client.

Further reading:

- [Issues running Xorg in 8 bit color mode:q](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2011-September/053331.html)
- [8 Bit / 256 Colors](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33266/8-bit-256-colors) (related discussion, different platform)
- [HowTo: Using Xephyr to Create a New Display in a Window](https://web.archive.org/web/20141029064912/http://jeffskinnerbox.me/posts/2014/Apr/29/howto-using-xephyr-to-create-a-new-display-in-a-window/)

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/256_Color_Mode) describes launching wine in 256 color mode, but approach works for any other application as well. The solution is to create new X11 display (one way or another) with desired capabilities and to run application within it. I tested VNC-way and it worked like a charm.